# PutAsync doesn't send request to web api, but fiddler works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I have been trying to figure out what is going wrong for a few hours now and i just can't find what is going wrong.

Via the Mvc application the put method doesn't get hit, the request doesn't happen. But when i test it in fiddler the PutMethod in the api works.

Hopefully someone can clear things up for me.

Also pointers for a better structure or some good documentation are welcome .

```
    public void UpdateWerknemerCompetentieDetail(int wnID, int WNC, CompetentieWerknemerDetail detail)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string token = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["token"];
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            var wn = GetWerknemerById(wnID);
            //var wnc = wn.CompetentiesWerknemer.Select(c => c).Where(c => c.ID == WNC).FirstOrDefault();
            detail.CompetentieWerknemerID = WNC;
            //wnc.CompetentieWerknemerDetail = detail;
            var url = String.Format(URL + "PutDetails?id=" + WNC);
             var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(detail, new JsonSerializerSettings()
             {
                 ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
             });         
            var response =  client.PutAsync(url, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        }
    }
```

The above code is my service that should make the request to the api.

Here is the web api IHttpActionResult method (the put method).

```
    [Route("PutDetails")]
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult PutWerknemerCompetentieDetails(int id, [FromBody]CompetentieWerknemerDetail cwn)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != cwn.CompetentieWerknemerID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        //_db.Entry(cwn).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            _db.CompetentieWerknemerDetail.Add(cwn);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!WerknemerExist(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`HttpClient.PutAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.putasync(v=vs.118).aspx) is an asynchronous API, it returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` which represents an operation which will complete in the future, which you need to `await`. You're wrapping your `HttpClient` inside a `using` statement, which means that right after you trigger the asynchronous PUT, you're disposing the client which causes a race condition with the request and the disposal of your object, and is probably the reason you're not seeing the request fire.

You have two choices. Either make the method `async Task` and `await` inside it:

```
public async Task UpdateWerknemerCompetentieDetailAsync(
        int wnID, int WNC, CompetentieWerknemerDetail detail)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string token = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["token"];
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        var wn = GetWerknemerById(wnID);
        //var wnc = wn.CompetentiesWerknemer.Select(c => c)
        //                                  .Where(c => c.ID == WNC)
        //                                  .FirstOrDefault();

        detail.CompetentieWerknemerID = WNC;
        //wnc.CompetentieWerknemerDetail = detail;
        var url = String.Format(URL + "PutDetails?id=" + WNC);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(detail, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
             ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });         
        var response = await client.PutAsync(
            url, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    }
}
```

Or use a synchronous API, such as exposed by [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks alot, I forgot about the fact that the client got disposed and that I needed to wait for the PutAsync to finish.