# sending data(model with register) to API with PutAsync but arrives without registration only Id

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to update a record through my API and upon arrival the data is empty.

Am I using the shipping method correctly?
What registration time should I send?

**CONTROLLER**

```
// POST: Category/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string id, Category_Model cate)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var category = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cate, Formatting.Indented));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:26457/api/Category/" + id), category);
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

**API**

```
// PUT: api/Category/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public void Put(string id, Category_Model category)
{
    var data = Builders<Category_Model>.Filter.Eq(d => d.Id, id);
    var update = Builders<Category_Model>.Update
            .Set(d => d.cod_Category, category.cod_Category)
            .Set(d => d.description_Category, category.description_Category)
            .Set(d => d.state_Category, category.state_Category);
    context.Category.UpdateOne(data, update);
}
```

[image]

I also tried:

1- [PutAsync doesn't send request to web api, but fiddler works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173165/putasync-doesnt-send-request-to-web-api-but-fiddler-works-fine)

2- [HttpClient PutAsync doesn't send a parameter to api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489611/httpclient-putasync-doesnt-send-a-parameter-to-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web API 2 - Method now allowed(405) for PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917372/web-api-2-method-now-allowed405-for-put)

Comment: In your controller signature, try adding `[FromBody]` before the parameter. e.g. `public void Put(string id, [FromBody] Category_Model category)`

Comment: @CraigH I was using that but it does not enter the API function

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not communicating the content type of the data in the call to the API.

You are creating a `StringContent` but nowhere are you informing the API that the content is actually JSON, so it probably just thinks it's a string and won't attempt to deserialize it into your object.

My suggestion would be to either...
Not serialize the object manually and let the HTTP client do the serialization work:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:26457/api/Category/" + id), cate);
```

Or, add content type information to the StringContent:

```
var category = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cate, Formatting.Indented), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_StringContent__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_System_String_) for the constructor of StringContent.